# How can I find out if someone logged onto my computer through putty?

Tags: 12.04, windows, putty

I am suspecting that a Windows user logged onto my computer with my password. So, is it possible that I can see a trace of logging in on my computer?

Comment: If that person had root access to your system (through sudo for example), then you effectively can't be sure they haven't tampered with the logs.

Answer (score 28):

**Method 1:**

> Get the user login history at any time

`last` command will give login history for a specific username. If we don’t give any argument for this command, it will list login history for all users. By default this information will read from `/var/log/wtmp` file. The output of this command contains the following columns:

- User name
- Tty device number
- Login date and time
- Logout time
- Total working time

Command: `$last jason`

```
jason   pts/0        dev-db-server   Fri Mar 27 22:57   still logged in
jason   pts/0        dev-db-server   Fri Mar 27 22:09 - 22:54  (00:45)
jason   pts/0        dev-db-server   Wed Mar 25 19:58 - 22:26  (02:28)
jason   pts/1        dev-db-server   Mon Mar 16 20:10 - 21:44  (01:33)
jason   pts/0        192.168.201.11  Fri Mar 13 08:35 - 16:46  (08:11)
jason   pts/1        192.168.201.12  Thu Mar 12 09:03 - 09:19  (00:15)
jason   pts/0        dev-db-server   Wed Mar 11 20:11 - 20:50  (00:39
```

**Method 2:**

You can also use the command `lastlog` command on Linux. It gives you more granular controls as to ranges of dates when looking through the logs of user logins.

> lastlog man page:

```
lastlog - reports the most recent login of all users or of a given user
```

> Example: To find out the users that have logged into a system in the last 100 days.

```
$ lastlog -b 0 -t 100
Username         Port     From             Latest
sam              pts/0    pegasus          Wed Jan  8 20:32:25 -0500     2014
joe              pts/0    192.168.1.105    Thu Dec 12 12:47:11 -0500 2013
```

This shows that the last times these users logged into this system. The range of time shows the last 100 days. Before today (-b 0) and after 100 days ago (-t 100).

You can also show all the users by omitting any range and just seeing every usre that's ever logged in, and the last time they logged in.

Comment: How can I delete my trace after login into his computer? :)

Comment: Try to override a file like this using sudo access: `>/var/log/wtmp`. This will delete all last log info.

Comment: The nice thing about wtmp is it's a sparse file. I can /tell/ if you delete a record from it.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `last` to show you the last logins. There is also a log file for authentication specific actions in `/var/log/auth.log`